# Ionic is installed in node modules globally but I receive: -bash: ionic: command not found

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

I am trying to install Ionic, however after I am installing this using the: `sudo npm install -g ionic` it returns with the next error: `-bash: ionic: command not found` for every command I am trying to use with the ionic CLI.

I have found the ionic folder in: `usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic` and tried to manually delete it by: `rm -rf ionic` and then tried to re-install it using the first command of installing ionic globally.

The ionic is getting created there but still receive the error of unknown command.

My npm version: **6.5.0**, my node.js version: **v9.2.0**

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `sudo`. This will cause the *"normal"* user to not have enough permissions to access the files written by the `sudo` user. Just install it like this

```
npm install -g ionic
```

Answer (score 0):

I have re-downloaded the Node.js from Node.js official website, re-installed and then did the sudo `npm install -g ionic` and it works. Node version was: **v9.2.0** and now it's **v10.15.1**